# jQuery - IF id of target element is like (match) - too much recursion error

Tags: jquery, recursion

I would like trigger different ajax call, based on id targeted.

My code:

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^=test1-order-done-],[id^=test2-order-done-]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $(this);
    var elemid = e.target.id;
    var id = elem.attr('data-id');
    console.log(e.target.id);
    var params = {
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            'updatestatus': orderstatus, 
            'updateorder': id
        },
        success: function() { elem.closest('tr').remove(); },
        error: function() { alert('ERROR'); }
    };
    if ( elemid == 'test1-order-done-' + id ) { params.url = 'test1_status_update.php'; } 
    if ( elemid == 'test2-order-done-' + id ) { params.url = 'test2_status_update.php'; }
    $.ajax(params);    
});
```

with that code i get "too many recursion" error. Where is the issue?

Comment: You probably have an infinite recursion in your script, but that does not seem to be in the piece of code that you posted. You should check the stack trace of the error and add it to your question.

Comment: fixed the issue, I forgot to include orderstatus as variable